# Batch deleting all rows left are going left and up instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to delete all rows in the tableView with a UITableViewRowAnimationLeft but the rows are not going just left there going twords the left top corner instead. Heres the code:

```
int aux = [dataSource count]-1;
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = aux; i>=0; i--)
{

    NSIndexPath *anIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [indexPaths addObject:anIndexPath];

}
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[table beginUpdates];
[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[dataSource removeAllObjects];
[table endUpdates];
```

What am i doing wrong? I just want the cels to animate to the left.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use animation TOP:

`[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];`

change it to left instead.

```
[table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Comment: That was a pasting mistake, even with the Left animation I'm getting the wrong animation

Comment: Can you try remove [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: I believe it's happened because you remove bunch of data at once. Can you try remove just one row and see is this remove to with animation left?

Comment: It does work for just one cell but I need them all to animate

Comment: Can you try different type of animation, for example UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic, UITableViewRowAnimationFade, etc. and see is it different or it's still the same animation?